# Organise files in SonataAdminBundle: what goes where?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I have regrouped the following information from a few examples in the `SonataAdminBundle` documentation. Please correct me if there are some errors, but here is what I get in the case of a `BlogBundle`:

[image: Frontend and Backend files are mixed in the same bundle]

As you can see, in general, each bundle contains both `frontend` and `backend` classes.

It seems very messy to mix both `frontend` and `backend` in the same folders somtetimes (see Controllers), but to be honest I can't think of an other way...

I actually started handling backend in a separate bundle but then realised that it was also too messy.

So in practice, do people really follow this architecture? Is this the only/best way to handle backend when using SonataAdminBundle?

This beautiful post [here](https://blog.liip.ch/archive/2011/05/19/symfony2-bundle-structure-a-use-case.html) is using a different approach...any ideas what I should do to make sure the code doesn't get too messy.

Comment: Entities of course play a role for the backend as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: use folders within locations of mixed content. I put frontend components directly in their respective folders, and add Admin folders for backend files.

You can refer to e.g. a controller in the Admin subfolder like this `BlogBundle:Admin\Concert:index`, essentially the same works for templates.

On configuration, you could create a `config-frontend.yml` and a `config-backend.yml` file, then include it in the original `config.yml` file. I don't do that though.